# I am trying to use an if statement on a document.getElementById but it changes the value instead

Tags: javascript

i am using this script

```
if (document.getElementById("pseudonym_session_unique_id").value = "help") {console.log("its true")}
```

to get the value of a string in a textbox, but it instead changes the value becuase of the = "" section, how do i ovveride the change

Comment: Should be `===` instead of `=`. `===` is checking for value and `=` is assigning value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using '=' means you are assigning a value to that variable.

For example,

```js
var x = 1 //where x is getting assigned with value 1
```

Using '==' means you are checking if something is equal to something else. This is not strict.

For example,

```js
x == 1 //is x equal to 1? (True)
x == 2 //is x equal to 2? (False)
```

Using '===' means you are checking if something is equal to something else. This is also strict.

Strict means, it checks not only the equality of the two values, but also it compares the types of the two values too.

For example,

```js
x === 1 //is x equal to 1? (True)
```

So, you need to use `===` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `===` instead of `=`

`===` is used to test for (strict) equality, while `=` is used to set a value.

Comment: I'd even specify to use ===. I'd never use == if possible.

Comment: Good call @Jacque, especially in this instance.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Actually `==` is better than `===`, since `===` tests for both value and type, while `==` only tests for value, so `6=="6" // true` while `6==="6" // false`.

Comment: @MrGeek those things not being treated as equal is a _good_ thing. Because they aren't equal. They are different things!

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I get you, I just meant that for a general case, say you have an input and I type `6`, it's a string when you get it by `input.value`, if you compare it with 6 using `input.value === 6` you'll get `false`, so just for safety, If not knowing what the output is, just use `==`.

Comment: @MrGeek, most people suggest not using `==` for safety. Those example values you've listed really _aren't_ equal because one is the string "6", and the other is the number value 6.
If you don't know what the output is, then you want to be even more careful than hoping it will coerce the value correctly. It leads to subtle bugs because it doesn't happen with every set of values.

Comment: @RodeoClown That's true, thank's for the explanation.

Comment: And as a side note, `==` comparison has to do more work than `===` under the hood since it tries a whole bunch of conversions.